# .properties file that contains spring-messages encoding error

Tags: spring-mvc, encoding, spring-messaging

In my web application(built on Spring Tool Suite) I maintain 2 .properties files to keep the website messages in greek and english language. I face the following problem. Sometimes in the file containing the greek messages, all messages loose encoding and are represented as question marks, as the following sample from my .properties file depicts:

```
valid.telephone.number=? ??????? ??? ???????? ?????? ?????????? ??????
valid.email=?? ?????? ????????? ???????????? ????????????
valid.url=?? ?????? ????????? ???????????? ??????????
valid.afm=?? ?????o ???
```

The problem occurs at random times, most of the times without even adding a new message to the file. The messages on the jsp's are correctly presented though. I haven't found a solution to my problem and everytime it occurs I just replace the file from our repository.

Answer (score 0):

If you have not set your encoding, try to set it to UTF-8.